# Down casting object and calling method

Tags: java

```
public class ExampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Upcasting from subclass to super class.
        A aRef=new C();

        //aRef.setMessage(); compilation Error     
        aRef.display();

        B bRef = (B)aRef;
        //bRef.setMessage(); compilation Error
        bRef.display();

        C cRef = (C)aRef;
        cRef.setMessage("ayaz");
        cRef.display();
    }
}

interface A
{
    void display();
}

class B implements A
{

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Am in class B");
    }

}

class C extends B
{
    String msg = "Am in class C";
    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    public void setMessage(String s){
        msg = s;
    }

}
```

In the above code after downcasting aRef object to an object of type B unable to call setMessage(),though on calling display with bRef Obj, display method of C class  is called. When we downcast to Obj of C then we are able to call why? is aRef only pointing to an object of type C, I think reference is not copied.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- at **compile time** the compiler looks at the type of the reference to determine if the method exists (is at least declared). So `aRef.display()` is correct as `bRef.display()` and `cRef.display()`. But `aRef.setMessage()` and `bRef.setMessage()` are incorrect (`setMessage`is not a method declared or defined in `A` or `B`. Of course `cRef.setMessage()` is correct.
- at **runtime** the machine finds the correct method to execute. As `aRef`, `bRef`and `cRef` refer to the same `C` object that redefines the method `display`, this one is called.

Answer (score 0):

Although the Object which resides in the heap is of Class C,the reference you have used is of Type B.You can only call the methods which exist in the reference and not the methods present in the actual Object.

1)Only Class C has `setMessage` method.So only a reference of Object C can invoke this method.Alternatively you can define these methods in interface and Class B and mark Class B as abstract with a concrete implementation in Class C

```
public class ExampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Upcasting from subclass to super class.
        A aRef=new C();

        aRef.setMessage(); //No compilation Error now    
        aRef.display();

        B bRef = (B)aRef;
        bRef.setMessage(); //No compilation Error now    
        bRef.display();

        C cRef = (C)aRef;
        cRef.setMessage("ayaz");
        cRef.display();
    }
}

interface A
{
    void display();
    void setMessage(String s);
}

abstract class B implements A
{

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Am in class B");
    }

}

class C extends B
{
    String msg = "Am in class C";
    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    public void setMessage(String s){
        msg = s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple rule is:

- The type of the variable tells what can be done
- The type of the object tells how to do it

Comment: `type of the variable :` define how the data will be represented and stored. `type of the object :` define the behavior of the object by method, essentially what are operation you can perform using a particular object.

Comment: as far as I know the type of a variable defines also the set of methods that can be use on the referenced object